# Convert multidimensional array to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a multidimensional array (retdata[R][C]) that basically looks like a spreadsheet of cells.  R represents the rows, C the columns.  I want to create an array of objects so that I get the following

```
 [{retdata[1][1]:retdata[2][1],retdata[1][2]:retdata[2][2],retdata[1][3]:retdata[2][3]    }, 
  {retdata[1][1]:retdata[3][1],retdata[1][2]:retdata[3][2],retdata[1][3]:retdata[3][3]    },
  {retdata[1][1]:retdata[4][1],retdata[1][2]:retdata[4][2],retdata[1][3]:retdata[4][3]    }, 
 etc...
]
```

The resulting array should be:

```
 [{"Col1":"dataR2C1","Col2":"dataR2C2", "Col3":"dataR2C3"}, 
 {"Col1":"dataR3C1","Col2":"dataR3C2", "Col3":"dataR3C3"}, 
 {"Col1":"dataR4C1","Col2":"dataR4C2", "Col3":"dataR4C3"}, 
 etc...
]
```

I have tried a number of options without success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is one example I have used but it id not serializing the objects properly.

```
                var TABLE = [];
                for (var i=2; i<=rows; i++) {
                    var ROW = {};                       
                    for (var j=1; j<=columns; j++){
                        name = retdata[1][j].toString;
                        value = retdata[i][j].toString;
                        ROW += {name: value}
                    }

                TABLE += ROW;   

                }
```

Comment: Show us something you've tried that's gotten you closer to the answer and we can help fix whatever is wrong with it. "I tried things but they didn't work" doesn't help anybody.

Comment: `I have a multidimensional array (retdata[R][C])` where? the code shown do not seems valid javascript

Comment: please try and describe your issue in general terms. abstraction of the problem will help us help you, and (more importantly) will assist you in understanding your own problem in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like a CSV-parser, the first row of your table are the keys for the line-objects. Your function would work, but you need to correct your array indices: they always start at `0`, running up to `n-1`. Also, you need to learn a bit JavaScript syntax:

- *something*`.toString` does not call the toString function on that value, but gets that function (it's just an object).
- You don't need toString at all - where needed, values are automatically casted
- You can't add key-value-pairs to object with a simple operator. You will need to assign the value to that property of an object, with the bracket notation. The `+=` operator would have casted the values to strings and concatenated them.
- It's the same with arrays. You could use the `.push()` method, or just assign to a numerical key - the javascript array object will automatically update its length.

```
var retdata = […];

var table = [],
    keys = retdata.shift(); // get & remove the first row
for (var i=0; i<retdata.length; i++) {
    var row = {};
    for (var j=0; j<retdata[i].length; j++)
        row[ keys[j] ] = retdata[i][j];
    table[i] = row;
}
```

Comment: can you please complete your code without the periods ... becouse I cant figure out in which case this will work

Comment: The `retdata` is just your multidimensional array - the periods suggest only that there is something in that already given array.

Comment: for a multidimensional array (perhaps similar to the one shown here, I mean similar becouse it is not valid JS syntax) your code may or may not work, and I want to understud.

Comment: This is the object *you* already have - show it to us (JSON-represented, if you want)!

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Bergi.  Here is my final solution:

```
              var TABLE = [];
                for (var i=2; i<=rows; i++) {
                    var ROW = {};                       
                    for (var j=1; j<=columns; j++){
                        ROW [retdata[1][j]] = retdata[i][j];
                    }
                TABLE[i]= ROW;  
                }
```

which works.  The shift did not work as expected but above code is just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: can you please post the complete solution including what retdata has on it?

Comment: retdata is basically like a spreadsheet.  The first row is headings and all other rows are the cell data.  I provided example data above in my original question.

Comment: this syntax `{retdata[1][1]:retdata[2][1],retdata[1][2]:retdata[2][2] ...` produces an error in JS becouse an array is used as an object property. I realy want to know what DATA works with this script